# Navigation bar tint color change

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

I have a navigation bar whose tint color is set, but when I navigate to other screen it looks bit different like in lighter than previous one..any idea why it is happening..how to fix this

Comment: Check on that specific view controller whether you have any change in tint color for navigation controller or something.

Comment: Does the other viewcontrollers have a lighter background?

Comment: Add the code of navigation bar color change. And if possible attach the images of both the screen

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your `rootViewController`

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Story Board select navigation Bar and change bar tint color

in image display with **red** mark.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same Navigation controller for all the ViewControllers in your project, then you need to set the tint colour in AppDelegate.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = colorToSet 
// colorToSet is an object of UIColor 
        return true
    }
```